# query to create same group id for all duplicate record

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have oracle table contain field like

```
rowindx,mdnnumber,poivalue,groupid
```

I want to assign same groupid to all record that are duplicate via `poivalue`.

I create function for that but i want to know is it possible with sql query ? how ?

Comment: How do you know which groupid to use? E.g., if one row with poivalue=1 has groupid=10 and another row also with poivalue=1 but groupid=11 which row should be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I can use the poivalue as the group ID sure.

```
Update table set GROUPID=PoiValue 
where POIValue in (
  Select POIValue 
  from table 
  group by poivalue 
  having count(poivalue) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

that should generate the groupid as 1,2,3...

```
update t
set    groupid = 
 (select groupid 
  from   (select poivalue, ROWNUM groupid
          from   (select distinct poivalue from t order by poivalue) t2) t2
          where  t2.poivalue = t.poivalue)
```